# Debugging reason for specific site sections with significantly low appearance in SERP

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, search-results

I'm experiencing very little exposure for specific sections in my site compared to different sections. Most of my traffic is long-tail queries, in the popular SERP, and non-popular SERP sections.

I know this is a pretty broad question, but, how would you suggest debugging possible reasons for this issue?

Specific Info:

- 'Problematic' pages are linked to from 'popular' pages and sitemap
- Most of Titles of 'Problematic' pages are similar to title of 'popular' pages, but not exactly the same.
- Most of these pages don't have many internal or external links
- These pages contain many photos and not a lot of text
- Google has indexed about 175k pages (from 1M), but only displays in SERP about 10.
- Pages don't include 'noindex'

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Please see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google?lq=1 for more information but your bullets indicate many low-quality flags and you are probably Panda'd and Penguin'd out of existence.

Comment: You also need to check duplicate content as you are having these many pages, chances are less to have Google quality unique content pages.

Comment: I was looking for specific advice regarding the difference between different sections that hold similar content, but one is get a lot of traffic, and the other none. I don't think this has anything to do with the 'duplicate question'. That question is very broad and has nothing to do with my case.